# How to write a generic log wrapper in ruby?

Tags: ruby, wrapper, python-decorators

In Python, I would have done that:

```
def with_logging(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Method: %s, Arguments: %s, %s" % (func.__name__, args, kwargs)
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print "Result: %s" % (res)
        return res
    return inner
```

and get:

```
>>> @with_logging
... def f(a, b):
...   return a + b
...
>>> f(2, 9)
Method: f, Arguments: (2, 9), {}
Result: 11
11
```

How can I achieve that in ruby? want to have some generic logging with method's name, args and output, without having to explicitly invoke logging inside each method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decorators in Ruby (migrating from Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891429/decorators-in-ruby-migrating-from-python)